# get a probeGC crash in Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crash, ios13

This crash is happening only on iOS 13.3.1 & 13.4.0

This crash is happening randomly and is a real deterrent to my customers.

I have update fabric library to lastest version (1.10.2).

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1947be090 objc_msgSend + 16
1  Foundation                     0x194e564f0 probeGC + 120
2  Foundation                     0x194d6cd64 -[NSConcreteMapTable rehashAround:] + 204
3  Foundation                     0x194d6cc68 -[NSConcreteMapTable removeObjectForKey:] + 248
4  UIKitCore                      0x198fbd484 _UIAnalyticsGatherMultitouchAnalytics + 632
5  UIKitCore                      0x198b38a10 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 204
6  UIKitCore                      0x198bb0c20 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 5880
7  UIKitCore                      0x198bb317c __handleEventQueueInternal + 4924
8  UIKitCore                      0x198babff0 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 108
9  CoreFoundation                 0x194a18a00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
10 CoreFoundation                 0x194a18958 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 80
11 CoreFoundation                 0x194a180f0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
12 CoreFoundation                 0x194a1323c __CFRunLoopRun + 1080
13 CoreFoundation                 0x194a12adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
14 GraphicsServices               0x19e9b3328 GSEventRunModal + 104
15 UIKitCore                      0x198b2063c UIApplicationMain + 1936
16 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                0x1029863dc main + 17 (main.m:17)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x19489c360 start + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you can get some information here:
*https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130095*